# Will my circuit work?

Tags: design

I have a circuit that I believe will work, but I was hoping someone could double check?

[Original schematic](https://5bbbafd3-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/picturehostingsites/home/storage/Full%20circuit.png?attachauth=ANoY7crX4hmofoCrpJ70FHVYAOfzZh2dDroYbQEqKFgJHrFmNpd8CVEtwFaXcLx5eYpV-__VXErWCNQMZnrHecSc3WrQBsfp1alBF659qCqbBcu_oDb6CDnX7Z0yqdQJsYZQvRxHTQGxK-6xf__wyB9VhiatJ8iAYw36yyhrUMTNmxhzxNYf3Nt4T8htR17jGVhSzJJlDFaN_SHx364X_5Z5YP18qE_gqAs-JJjHBLmN8YVdbzN_yRETYDlw27ndJMDEYTDjTEPW&attredirects=0)

In my circuit, I use a [MOSFET](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/IXFP5N100PM/IXFP5N100PM-ND/4234033), a [photo-interrupter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10-Pieces-5-16-Slot-PCB-Photo-Interrupter-Sensor-HY860H-/171325143377?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27e3c63951), a [CVCC](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5A-LED-Drive-Power-Supply-Module-Step-Down-CVCC-75W-Lithium-Battery-Charger-/400695001209?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5d4b488079), several resistors, a battery, and an LED.

The load has a resistance about 2.525Ω

Assuming that the CVCC is required, would my circuit work?

Also, the purpose of this circuit is switching. When the photo-interrupter beam is intact, the load gets no current. When the beam is broken, the load gets current. Or, that's the idea here.

Changed freewheeling diode to Shottky diode as suggested.

Current Schematic:
[image]

Comment: Explain how it is supposed to work. Step us through what the user would expect to see (and do) when the power source is turned on. You have an opto-isolator that will always be on when power is applied. There's no actual isolation in the circuit, so why the isolator?

Comment: @DanLaks, notice the optocoupler is labelled as "opto-interruptor"

Comment: I assume isolator is sort of a switch when there is any interference of any object blocking the infrared light the circuit will be open/isolated. Is that true?

Comment: You've made some changes since we talked about this in chat. In chat you talked about a solenoid as the load, but here you're showing a resistive load. In chat you talked about a 12 V supply, here you're showing 2 V. Could you make sure the schematic actually shows what you're trying to do?

Comment: @ThePhoton, ah, thanks for pointing that out. I made an assumption when looking at the circuit without reading the description carefully.

Comment: The resistors R1/R2 are a bit low if power supply voltage is any different than 2V.

Comment: @ThePhoton Since a solenoid is a coil of wire, it can be represented by the schematic symbol for an inductor, _or_ a resistor. I chose resistor is all. Also, the CVCC keeps the voltage at 2V.

Comment: @jippie The voltage should stay at 2V, again, the CVCC should do that.

Comment: Why not power the electronics from battery and the coil from CVCC?

Comment: @DanLaks The circuit is just a big switching system. When the photo-interrupter is blocked by something (paper, a finger, etc.), the load receives current. I'm basing this off of another [circuit](http://tesla3.com/free_websites/zpe_lindemann_attraction_lighty1.gif), so I believe it should work.

Comment: @jippie Please note the _size_ of the battery. I would much rather have a CVCC powering everything then wast power using resistors to drop 11.4V to 0.02V

Comment: @CoilKid, In this case the inductive properties are more important, and drawing it as an inductor will help you get better answers.

Comment: -1 for not supplying a spec for what the circuit is *supposed* to do.  You ask whether it works, but there is no way to tell without knowing intended behaviour.  This should be obvious.  We do engineering here, not handwaving or guessing.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I already said what is supposed to do. The load is supposed to get current when the photo-interrupter is blocked. Even if I had not said, there's not much else this circuit _could_ do.

Comment: @ThePhoton Okay, can do. Will change the schematic to mirror.

Comment: No, I just re-read your question and you *still* haven't said what it is supposed to do.  Perhaps you mentioned something in comments, but I'm not going to read a large chain of comments like this to get basic information.  The question needs to stand on its own.  If you have new information, it should be edited into the question.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Re-edited to show purpose.

Comment: @CoilKid, when you remove the old images, it makes the work people did previously to answer your question hard to understand. -1 for making this question a moving target.

Comment: @ThePhoton If you like, I could probably have links to the old ones. I don't think I should add them to the OP though, because it would make it unbearably _long_.

Answer (score 7):

It won't work, your MOSFET has a V<sub>GS(Th)</sub> of 3 V. Your supply is only 2 V.

What is this circuit for; if we know we can help you better?

Answer (score 6):

I'm sorry to say that your circuit will not work:

- The MOSFET R<sub>DS(on)</sub> (2.8 Ω) is too big compared to your load resistance (2.5 Ω). If your load needs 2 V to work properly, be aware that it will only have around 1 V (assuming the MOSFET was fully on, which as mentioned above, it won't be).
- The LED (indicating if the load is powered) has no current limiting resistor. You should add a small resistor (330 Ω will be ok)
- Your circuit switches the power ON when your opto-interrupter is occluded. If you needed it to works the other way around, you may want to use a P-MOSFET.

Comment: The load requires a target _current_ of 1A. As far as I know, the voltage shouldn't matter. The LED I can make switch directions easily enough(And thanks for telling what it does). And the circuit is _supposed_ to me ON when the interrupter beam is broken. Also, with the Vgs(th) doesn't R3 bump the voltage back to about 6.3V?

Comment: "(And thanks for telling what it does)" sorry I didn't meant to be rude. I was just assuming it was the purpose of the led, so you could have corrected my answer in case it was not.
Your schematic indicate a +2V power supply at the top. Were you meaning +12V ? If it is indeed +12V your circuit will work flawlessly. If it is only 2V, then it's impossible to have 6.3V anywhere in the circuit. Your CVCC will adjust the voltage to match the desired current, so maybe the supply voltage will be enough to drive the mosfet... Test it ! :P

Comment: No reason to think you were rude. I honestly had no idea what it did. The [schematic](http://tesla3.com/free_websites/zpe_lindemann_attraction_lighty1.gif) I am basing this off of had a diode, and a lamp. Turning on when the load is active would make sense. Thanks!

Comment: I adjusted my circuit to 5V, would it work now? I really don't want to wast energy bringing 11.4V to 0.02V and 0.05V. Therefore, _CVCC!_

Comment: Actually, do I even _need_ R3? If I can't use it to bump the voltage past Vgs(th), then why do I need it?

Comment: Can you tell me what is your load exactly ?

Comment: A solenoid. Basically, a resistor or inductor. As I said above in my OP, it has a resistance of about 2.525Ω.

Comment: I think it's better to keep R3 in place. It protects the mosfet gate.

Comment: If your load is inductive, you will need a freewheel diode (I think it was the purpose of the Led in first place). A solenoid will push back energy into the circuit when shut off abruptly.

Comment: Okay, but Does the resistance have to be that high? It would be easier for me to buy one with 100Ω than 300. (I think)

Comment: Well, it _could_ be. I would assume so, just to be safe. The MOSFET has a nS switching time though, right?

Comment: Switching time can be found in datasheet. But the gate of a mosfet being capacitive, in your case the R3 value will kind of 'tweak' the switching time. The bigger the resistance, the longer the switching time.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'll look into that. Thanks! Besides R3, does the circuit work well?

Comment: With 5V supply I think you are more or less good to go :) Also you can check for a better mosfet. This one is pretty old and will suck a lot of power for nothing. Try to get a mosfet with a Rdson < 0.1 ohm.

Comment: Okay. I actually chose that one, because it was the only one that I saw on Digikey that matched my specs and was less than $10

Comment: Okay I'll try to find a better one quickly. The max current is still 1 Amp ?

Comment: This one should do the trick, but it is surface mount. https://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/FD/FDN339AN.pdf
Good luck !

Comment: These two guys in digikey will also work in you circuit. http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/IRLD024PBF/IRLD024PBF-ND/812492
http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/IRLD014PBF/IRLD014PBF-ND/812481
And they are trough hole.

Comment: How would I use a 4 lead FET? I only know how to use the 3 lead ones.

Comment: I changed the resistors in my schematic also, because I mixed them up the first time.

Comment: Thanks! Just saw the fairchildsemiconductor just now. I guess I will have to get better at soldering.

Comment: Look at the datasheet, there is just 3 pins in fact. ;)

Comment: Well, I meant the ones on Digikey. The Fairchild semiconductor should work (still need to double check, but thank you for finding it!). I asked about a 4 pin FET before I saw the 3 pin one. :)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the too low supply voltage there is another issue. If the LED is intended to light when the load is activated you will need to turn the LED around the other way and place a resistor in series with the LED to limit it's forward current. In the end the LED may not even light if the supply voltage is kept lower than the forward voltage drop of the LED.

Comment: Huh.. That's something to think about...

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to tell whether you circuit will "work" since you haven't said what it should do.  "Working" means the actual behaviour matches the specification.  Obviously that requires a specification, which is missing in your case.

What this circuit will do is to blow out the LED when the light is interrupted.  Whether that is the desired behaviour and it is therefore "working", we can't tell.

Some observations:

R1 is very low.  LEDs in opto-interruptors usually have around 1.2 V forward drop at rated current.  100 Ω for R1 sets the LED current at 38 mA in that case.  Are you sure that is within spec?  Even if it is, does the light really need to be that strong?

R3 is pointless.  Replace is with a short.

R2 seems rather low, but I haven't checked the opto-interruptor datasheet (that's your job).  For the opto output transistor to turn on fully, it has to sink about 19 mA.  Can it do that?  Does it really need to?  If R1 were 1 kΩ instead, the transistor would only need to sink about 5 mA.  The only drawback would be a little longer rise time in turning on the FET when the light is obstructed.

There current thru the output LED is not limited.  If the FET turns on fully, which should happen when the light is interrupted, most of the 5 V supply voltage will be applied to the LED, which will damage it.  If this is a typical green LED, then figure it has about 2.1 V accross it when lit.  A 150 Ω resistor in series with the LED will allow about 20 mA thru it, which most LEDs can handle.  Check the datasheet of your particular LED though.

### Update:

You have now changed your circuit again.  Since this seems to be a moving target, I'm including your latest version here so that it's clear what I'm answering:

[image]

The LED now shouldn't blow up, and the useless FET gate resistor has been removed, but there are other issues:

Assuming the opto-interruptor has a typical IR LED which drops 1.2 V at useful current, the LED is now being driven 15 mA.  That's fine.

With the new value of R2, the output transistor in the opto must sink about 48 mA to bring its output about as low as it can go.  I don't see a need for such large current.  Low impedance gate drive will make faster edges, but I doubt the opto is so fast that going to this low a impedance makes any difference.

Another issue is that now you are requiring the opto to have a current tranfer ratio of (48 mA)/(15 mA) = 3.2.  I suppose that's possible, but it would be rather unusual for a opto-interruptor.  These often have current transfer ratios less than 1.

As I said before, I'd make R2 1kΩ.  That would require the output transistor to only sink 4.8 mA, which requires the otpo to have a current transfer ratio of only 1/3, which a lot more opto-interruptors can do.

I meant to say this earlier, but somehow it slipped thru the cracks.  You need a kickback catch diode accross the load since it is inductive.  For such low voltages, I'd use a Shottky.  The diode is connected in reverse accross the inductor so that it doesn't conduct when the inductor is on.  When a inductor is suddenly switched off, it will maintain the instantaneous current somehow.  The diode provides a nice safe path for that current.  Without that, the inductor will create whatever voltage is necessary to maintain the same current in the short term, possibly blowing out the LED and/or the FET in the process.

### Update 2:

Added point 3 to the list above.

Comment: As I believe I have already said somewhere here, its supposed to run current through the load if the interrupter is blocked, and If it helps I can put in in the OP. My _photo_ -interrupter runs at a max of 20mA for the diode, and 50mA for the transistor. At least, that's what I got from the specs. Also, I need R3 to adjust the gate capacitance on the FET(or so I've been told). I will probably take your advice about the status LED, as its good advice.

Comment: Sorry, had those specs backward. The interrupter diode can take 50mA and the transistor can take 20mA.

Comment: @Coil: No, you don't need R3 to "adjust the gate capacitance on the FET".  That makes no sense anyway.  There are sometimes situations to put a resistor in series with a FET gate, but this not one of them.  You probably heard someone say that it is necessary because he always does it for religious reasons without thinking about what purpose it is actually serving.

Comment: Huh. Okay, I guess I can get rid of it then.

Comment: Also, I changed the resistors around because I mixed them up.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the resistors. I'd like to apologize for mixing up my resistor values again. I have a whiteboard with all the circuit specs on it, and I mixed one up. R2 should read "300Ω"

Comment: Isn't that what the freewheeling diode should do? I thought it was set to go the other direction from the LED?

Comment: @Coil: Yes, this is sometimes called a "freewheeling diode".  I see now that you updated the schematic in your question *again*.  This iteration has a diode as I mentioned, although as I said I'd make it a Shottky.  However I see the silly R3 is back and dubious part values.  Oh well, I'm done here.  If you're not going to listen to advice, then it's pointless for me to spend time writing it.

Comment: Hey. I put R3 back to  keep the inductor from damaging the FET. I just heard "Diode" If you suggest a Shottky, I will probably put a Shottky in. As to "Dubious part values" I don't know what R3 should be to help keep the inductor from damaging the diode, but if you can prove I don't need it, then I will take it out. If you don't want to help that's your choice. I wish you luck with whatever project _you_ work on next.